# How to start Firefox maximized or fullscreen without any additional extensions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox

How can I start Firefox maximized or fullscreen without any additional extensions?

If I open it, maximize and then close it, it still does not open maximised.

The OS is linux - Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit

Comment: Please add your operating system

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use command line options, e.g. for a 1600x1200 resolution display use:

```
firefox -height 1200 -width 1600
```

Comment: This resolved my issue!